# What does `A(::2,3) = -1.0` do in Fortran?

Tags: fortran90

I have a matrix `A` declared as `real :: A(7,8)` and intialised so that all entries are `0.0`.

The following command does not provide any compiling errors.

```
A(::2,3) = -1.0
```

I realise that the columns affected will be only column 3.
What about the rows? Does `::2` mean rows `1` and `2`? Or something else?

I printed out the matrix, but couldn't understand the pattern produced.

Here (for completeness):

```
do, i=1,7
    write(*, "(f5.2)") ( A(i,j), j=1,8 )
enddo

 0.00 i = 1
 0.00
-1.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 2
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 3
 0.00 
-1.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 4
 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 5
 0.00
-1.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 6
 0.00
 0.00 
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00 ----
 0.00 i = 7
 0.00
-1.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
 0.00
```

Looking at it now, it looks like it starts at `i=1` and adds 2 to `i` until it reaches the bounds of the matrix. Is this correct?

Does this mean that `::2` is equivalent to `1:7:2` ("from 1 to 7 with a step of 2)?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for better visibility. Fortran 90 is just one specific (and old) version.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5257/blagu/index.html), we see:

> ```
> print array-expression [first-expression : last-expression : stride-expression]
> ```
>
> where:
>
> `array-expression` Expression that should evaluate to an array type.
>
> `first-expression` First element in a range, also first element to be
>   printed. Defaults to lower bound.
>
> `last-expression` Last element in a range, but might not be the last
>   element to be printed if stride is not equal to 1. Defaults to upper
>   bound.
>
> `stride-expression` Length of the stride. Defaults to 1.

So if `first-expression` and `last-expression` are omitted, they default to lower bound and upper bound respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right - it's the same as 1:7:2, as you can see from the output, it's setting the 3rd element in the sub-array to -1 for every 2nd sub array